# Lambda Expression casting to Observable Collection

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, lambda

If I have an object of type Person and it has a navigation property of PersonAddressJoin which then has addresses.

```
PersonResults= new ObservableCollection<Person>(_op.Entities.OfType<Person>());
```

and I want to then take the PersonAddressJoin navigation property and put that into an object.
so i have an ObservableCollection AddressList

```
AddressList = PersonResults.SelectMany(x => x.PersonAddressJoins);
```

when i do it this way I get a message that says I cant cast an IEnumberable to an ObservableCollection.?

Can someone help me get that navigation property into this object...thanks

Comment: Do you want the `ObservableCollection` to change whenever a `Person` changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of SelectMany is an IEnumerable.  Untested, but try:

```
AddressList = new ObservableCollection<PersonAddressJoins>(PersonResults.SelectMany(x => x.PersonAddressJoins));
```